# PHP execution halts for unknown reason

Tags: php, interpreter

Execution of my PHP script halts if I have this piece of code in it with no error

```
return str_replace( 
    str_repeat($currentOsSeparator, 2),
    '//',
    str_replace(
        $separators,
        $currentOsSeparator,
        $path),
    1);
```

Now, the tricky part is that execution stops even if this code is **after** a return statement.

Comment: You set error_reporting?

Comment: Please show more context. What comes before this code? What comes after (if anything)?

Comment: smells of a parse error, error reporting would certainly help you.

Comment: Spread that code out to help you find the error.  Store `str_repeat($currentOsSeparator, 2)` and `str_replace(
        $separators,
        $currentOsSeparator,
        $path)` in a temp variable and see if they run.

Comment: Well, frankly, the question is mostly of interest because it halts execution when placed after a `return` statement inside a method.

Answer (score 1):

Is that supposed to be a function? Not sure what you're trying to do. The error returned for the above code on its own is

> PHP Fatal error:  Only variables can be passed by reference

You should read this:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php

> If called from the global scope, then execution of the current script file is ended

But without seeing more of your code or more explanation it's hard to help.

Comment: James, thanks, I realized this shortly after posting the question - passing a variable to the function fixed the problem. However, this code was not in the global scope - it was inside a static method - and halted execution even if there was another `return` statement before it, which makes me think it's a parser error of some sort. Any more ideas?